# Grails params.controller bug

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

In a gsp you should be able to reference params.controller and use it for something like highlighting the current menu item
eg  class='active'

This technique works for me but only 80% of the time. Sometimes params.controller is blank and so is params.action by the time the gsp template is rendered.

I am using grails 2.4.3.
I have even tried storing the current controller in a request variable in a filter but this is no more reliable than params.controller accessed directly via a gsp.

any suggestions are most welcome. thanks for your help.

Comment: It will be null for direct gsp requests. Is there any pattern to what works and what doesn't? Does it sometimes work for a controller but then not work later?

Comment: Hi Burt. It sometimes works and sometimes not. in a gsp. Even in a filter it is not always working. I think there must be a bug in Grails with this. I have had to do a regular expression to make it work using the request.forwardURI. <g:if test='${request.forwardURI =~ /blah\/blahblah/}'> class='selected</g:if>. But this is not ideal. I would rather that grails could handle it using the params.controller and action which works about 7 times out of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `params.controller` you could use the `controllerName` variable. This should always be set to the name of the current controller, but will be empty for direct GSP requests because there is no controller involved

Comment: even if you define it as a passing value where pages get rendered on the controller ? so from your controller: render view: 'something, model: [controller:controllerName, action:actionName] and now current controller is ${controller}  - obviously this now means declaring it when needed

Comment: @Londoner could you show the code that you're trying to use with `controllerName`?